# How do you find the parameters of a surface integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

$$ \iint_S x+y+z \,dσ $$

$$ 0 \leq x,y,z \leq 1 $$

I have this surface integral where $S$ is the surface of a cube. How do I find the parameters $x,y$ and $z$?
Also,what does the second inequality means? Does it means that the values of $x,y$ and $z$ are between $0$ and $1$?
I have read the chapter of surface integrals but I didn't understand a lot from the theories. Is it about a function in space $f(x,y,z)$ ?

Comment: Hint: By symmetry, one has $ \iint_S x+y+z \,dσ =3 \iint_S x\,dσ.$

Comment: @xpaul What do you mean and where did that 3 appered from?

Comment: $\iint_S x\,dσ= \iint_S y\,dσ= \iint_S z \,dσ$.

Comment: Can Someone Explain?

Comment: If you change $x->y->z$, they are the same.